# How to handle password storage for my project?

Tags: python, encryption, virtual-machine, password-encryption, lib-nfc

I'm currently planning a project that will unlock a Pi with NFC and then log in to RDP. The users will never need to know the password to login to the VM, since their NFC card will handle the log-in. So how to approach this?

I was thinking:
A NFC Card has a unique ID, check the database for the ID, get the corresponding password and then send this to rdesktop.

But there's a problem with that, I don't want to create a potential security problem, if the database gets hacked, someone can get into someone elses VM, I don't want that to happen.

So my question: What's the most secure approach to this? And if I hash my passwords, how can I retrieve them again?

Comment: Topics like this are too broad for SO, unfortunately. This might not be exactly what you are looking for. But it might give you ideas, considering it explains details about NFC and authentication with Android. http://nelenkov.blogspot.ca/2014/03/unlocking-android-using-otp.html

Comment: @idjaw Let me reformulate my question, NFC is not relevant at all, I think personally. It's just matching a certain number to a certain entry in a (mysql?) database and then retrieving the "password" value. 

I'm rather looking for a safe way to do that, the rdesktop program needs to receive the password as plaintext via the command line.

Comment: The security stackexchange is probably better suited for this.

Comment: Hashing passwords is the correct approach to ensure that no one can steal them. You're not meant to be able to retrieve them yourself. You should only compare hashes to verify authorisation, and if a password is forgotten, use some other means to authenticate a password reset. That's why websites always email you a password reset link if you forget your password. They don't send you your password because even they aren't supposed to know what it is.

Comment: @AlexHall That's fun, but the thing is, I need to be able to do so.
I reposted my question in The Security stackexchange, thanks!